# Install ros_gazebo package on Gazebo (not classic)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My environment i ROS2 Humble, and installed gazebo using `sudo apt-get install ros-humble-ros-gz`.
I need to install `gazebo_ros` package, but since I don't use Gazebo-classic (?), the docs:

https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros

apparently does not apply. But link from the warning on top of the "old" documentation page only lead to

https://gazebosim.org/docs,

in other words the link is broken. Also the link titled "Overview of new ROS integration" is broken.

Much appreciated if anyone could spell out the installation procedure on Ubuntu 22, or just link to the correct documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29184/install-ros_gazebo-package-on-gazebo-(not-classic)/) by [Simple Simpson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/192520/simple-simpson/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

https://gazebosim.org/docs is the best source of documentation for installing Gazebo. If you want to use ROS, there's a whole section there that describes the steps.

You said you need to install `gazebo_ros`, but `ros-humble-ros-gz` is the equivalent of `gazebo_ros` (which is for Gazebo-classic) for the new Gazebo. If you already have `ros-humble-ros-gz` installed, you just need to install Gazebo Fortress

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2023-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Simple Simpson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/192520/simple-simpson/) on 2023-06-21**:
I'll admit being confused, I thought `sudo apt-get install ros-humble-ros-gz` actually installed Gazebo. From the doc [paragraph](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/ros_installation#installing-gazebo-with-older-versions-of-ros):

> The following command will install the correct version of Gazebo and ros_gz for your ROS installation on a Linux system.

I can open Gazebo by `gz sim empty.sdf`, but get `package 'gazebo_ros' not found` when running a launch file intended to spawn a robot in Gazebo.

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2023-06-21**:
Ah, my mistake, it looks like `ros-humble-ros-gz` indirectly depends on `libignition-gazebo6`, so yes, it does install it. If you have a launch file that is looking for `gazebo_ros`, that launch file is probably meant to be used with Gazebo-classic. It'll need to be updated to work with the new Gazebo.

**Comment by [Simple Simpson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/192520/simple-simpson/) on 2023-06-22**:
cool, thanks. Do you have any links to documentation how to replace `gazebo_ros` references with new Gazebo?

**Comment by [Simple Simpson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/192520/simple-simpson/) on 2023-06-22**:
Reading the [docs](https://index.ros.org/r/gazebo_ros_pkgs/#humble), `gazebo_ros` is still a package name, right?

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2023-06-22**:
`gazebo_ros` is still a package name, but it's meant to work with Gazebo classic. You'll want to use `ros_gz` with the new Gazebo. [Here's](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz_project_template) a repo with examples. This [video](https://vimeo.com/showcase/9954564/video/767127300) should also help

**Comment by [Simple Simpson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/192520/simple-simpson/) on 2023-06-22**:
thanks man!